# Add a custom code with custom link after add to cart for every product

Tags: php, button, woocommerce, e-commerce, hook-woocommerce

Let's say I need to add a custom code so visitors can visit the product's external site. That way they can visit the product's site.

What I want to achieve is as follows:

Add a custom code after the add to cart button;
The link to the custom code needs to be set in each product edition.
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function importHotmart(){
        var imported = document.createElement('script');
        imported.src = 'https://static.hotmart.com/checkout/widget.min.js';
        document.head.appendChild(imported);
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = 'https://static.hotmart.com/css/hotmart-fb.min.css';
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }
    importHotmart();
</script>
<a onclick="return false;" href="*" class="hotmart-fb hotmart__button-checkout">Buy now</a>
```

To woocomerce store

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this code up has a poup checkout link, for each product, I have a different checkout link I change it I code up, I want to add the code up for each product with a different checkout link for each product